# Pre-linnaean names, where can I ask about current IDs?

Tags: botany, taxonomy, history

I run a large website with lots of historical herb books. For the older ones, finding out current botanical names is very difficult.

Can I ask here? If not, does anybody know where I could ask what any given plant is, with or without images, usually with descriptions and pre-Linnaean names?

Comment: Where are you located geographically? Your best bet might be to get in touch with local botanists who are likely familiar with the local flora mentioned in the herb books. If you’re in the US, an organization like the Smithsonian Transcription Centre might be able to help you out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smithsonian_Transcription_Center

Comment: I'm in Northern Europe. The old books are from Europe or the US, variously. I'll try the Smithsonian, thanks!

Comment: Ooo, nice! There’s a ton of biodiversity resources in Europe. I’m not sure who’d be best to approach first here (and I hope someone who does posts an answer to your question!), but this might be a good place to start: https://www.kew.org/blogs/kew-science/celebrating-50-years-of-library-collaboration

Comment: Kew isn't interested in pre-Linnaean, I've asked them. Or at least, I asked their "current botanical name database" people.

Comment: The Smithsonian botany set is complete, looks to be mostly herbarium specimens, with current botanical names. I don't think they do pre-Linnaean. (I do have Linné's works, of course, which helps a little.)

Comment: In case you're not aware, a late 19th century edition of _Culpeper's complete herbal_ gives binomial names for many of the entries, and is freely available at archive.org

Comment: Culpeper is easy: http://medherb.com/culpeper_names.html

Salmon's Botanologia 1710 is difficult, here, for instance:
"Of Water Agrimony the Male Kind"
In Latin, Eupatorium aquaticum mas, Eupatorium Cannabinum mas, Agrimonia aquatica mas

It is ... the Genus to three other Kinds:
1. Our English Male Water Agrimony.
2. The New-England, or Hemp-like Agrimony.
3. The Virginian Kind. 

I think #1 is Eupatorium cannabinum, #2 Eupatorium maculatum, and #3 could be Acnida cannabina or Amaranthus cannabinus. 

Alas, Salmon has hundreds of such entries. Other old herbals can be as cryptic.